# Powershell cannont use Invoke-Command from my computer

Tags: powershell-2.0, remote-access, invoke-command

I'm creating a little script which need to send some scriptblock on remote computer. For this i'm using Invoke-Command.

I had some issue to connect to the remote computer (winrm and enable-psremoting enabled on the remote computer) from my computer.

I just noticed that if I ran my script from another computer i don't have any problem - it is working and connecting to the remote computer with Invoke-Command.

I'm using an account provided by -credential which is local administrator of the remote computer so I don't think it's related to my account but rather to my computer but i can't find why.

Here is the french error message :

> [computername] La connexion au serveur distant a échoué avec le
>   message d'erreur suivant : La connexion à l'hôte distant spécifié a
>   été rejetée. Vérifiez que le service Gestion des services Web est en
>   cours d'exécution sur l'hôte distant et configuré pour écouter les
>   demandes sur le port et l'URL HTTP corrects. Pour plus d'informations,
>   voir la rubrique d'aide about_Remote_Troubleshooting. 
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [],
>   PSRemotingTransportExc     eption 
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionOpenFailed

This could probably translated to something like that :

> [computername] The connection to the remote host was refused. Verify
>   that the WS-Management service is running on the remote host and
>   configured to listen for requests on the correct port and HTTP URL.

Any idea ?

Comment: Additionnal information : It's neither a firewall issue, i cant connect remotely to the computer on the port 5985 using either telnet or chrome.

Comment: i can* i can connect remotely*. there is no t here :x